# My page could not be found, can someone help me?

Tags: laravel, api, postman

Here is my function in the controller

```
public function list()
    {
            $customers = Customer::all();
            foreach ($customers as $customer) {
                $list = [

                    'Customer ID' => $customer->id,
                    'Customer Name' => $customer->full_name,
                ];
                $lists[] = $list;
            }
            $collection = $this->paginate($lists, $perPage = 5, $page = null, $options = []);
            return new mainCollection($collection);
    }
```

and here is my route

```
Route::get('customers/list', 'customerController@list')
```

When I access http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers/list in PostMan I have error 404 Not Found
Another Route works well.
can someone help me?

Comment: Can you post your api.php routes file and the complete controller code?

Comment: it's too big my controller to put here

Comment: Check php artisan route:list / double check your route info. Also, check your controller class name and namespace.

Comment: Can you accept the comment as an answer?

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: I have posted it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `php artisan route:list` / double check your route info.

Also, check your controller class name and namespace.